# Elevar un valor en base 10 - C++

Tags: c++

Muy buenas a todos. Me ha surgido una duda cuando hacía un programa en C++. ¿Podrían decirme cómo realizar la siguiente operación? -> 5.10^8. Esto no es lo mismo que pow(5,8), por ello desconozco cómo podría calcularlo.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente  `5 * pow(10, 8)`?

Comment: Es muy fácil: debes multiplicar cinco por diez elevado a ocho.

Comment: Es cierto, se lo agradezco ;]